# Convert const char* to LPCTSTR

Tags: c, windows, string, mfc

I have a function that returns me a string as `const char *`:

```
const char* get_text();
```

I need to call a function `AfxMessageBox(LPCTSTR text)`.

How can I convert the string that I got by `get_text()`?

Comment: What it the encoding (charset) of the string returned by get_text()? The thing is that LPCTSTR depends on character set in your project settings: for non-Unicode it's the same as const char*, and for Unicode it is const wchar_t*. Most probably you are trying to get a Unicode string, but then you should know what's the charset of the source string.

Comment: @Inspired the `get_text` returns a regular ASCII string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're using MFC and assuming a UNICODE build (or you wouldn't have this error!), probably the simplest way is to instantiate a `wchar_t` compatible `CString` directly:

```
CStringW szWide(getText());
AfxMessageBox(szWide);
```

Comment: Alternatively you could use one of the [ATL and MFC String Conversion Macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/87zae4a3.aspx): `AfxMessageBox( CA2CT( getText() ) );`. The answer provided by Roger is however easier to follow.